# Cómo recorro todos los valores de un objeto json con gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

Estoy utilizando gson. Y tengo esto:

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(["1156","1157","1160"]).getAsJsonObject();
```

Necesito recorrer ese objeto gson para formar al final esta cadena: `1156|1157|1160`

Pero, ¿cómo recorro un objeto json con gson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad la estructura que indicas es un `JSON Array`, no un `JSON Object` que usaría "{" "}" como contenedores :

```
"["1156","1157","1160"]"
```

Para recorrer el JSON Array  lo realizarías de esta forma, ejemplo:

```
        String resultado="";

        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray("["1156","1157\",\"1160\"]");

            for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
                 resultado += array.get(i) + ((i<array.length()-1)?"|":"");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Para obtener un valor en la variable `resultado` de:

```
1156|1157|1160
```

---

En el caso de tu ejemplo, puedes usar las clases clases de [**Google GSON**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson):

```
com.google.gson.JsonArray;
com.google.gson.JsonParser;
```

y usarías `JsonArray` en lugar de `JsonObject` ya que la estructura en realidad es un Json Array, ejemplo:

```
    String resultado="";
    JsonArray array = new JsonParser().parse("[1156,1157,1160]").getAsJsonArray();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.size() ; i++){
        resultado += array.get(i) + ((i<array.size()-1)?"|":"");
    }
```

Para obtener un valor en la variable `resultado` de:

```
1156|1157|1160
```

---

Revisa la respuesta y dependiendo de eso recuerda que la respuesta .Json puede ser de dos tipos:

> - Si el .json inicia con **"{"** se considera como objeto Json (Json Object).
> - Si el .json inicia con **"["** es considerado como Arreglo Json (Json Array).

Comment: Excelente, gracias

Comment: @user2930137, Agregué a mi respuesta también como usar la clase Gson para este caso. Saludos!